# Can any one prove this logical equation in digital electronics,[a xor b xor c xor d=(a xnor b xnor c xnor d)' ]where (') means compliment

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

A xor B XOR C XOR D = (A XNOR B XNOR C XNOR D)!
Where ! Means compliment,can you tell me if the equation is correct and if so how?

Comment: Just create a truth table and compare

Answer (score 1):

This equation does not really need a proof. The definition of an xnor gate is an xor gate with an inverted output. If you invert the output of an xnor gate you get back to an xor gate.